# How to use retrieve weekly data from daily data series?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a data series which consists of daily data in one worksheet in Excel 2010.

I also have an array (because of some matrix multiplication) in it, and I cannot create a table with an array in it, so I can't really use vlookup (or can I? Someone please enlighten me).

I need to retrieve data every 7 days for some testing from this particular column in the first sheet.

How do I use vlookup (or something similar) to get the data every 7 days into another worksheet beside it? I have the dates as the first column.

Comment: not familiar with any of them. which is the easiest/fastest/best way to do this?

Comment: This site is really designed to help with specific problems. Although you ask a good question, it is difficult to answer because it seems you lack basic knowledge of how Excel works. You might want to start here...[Basic tasks in Excel 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/basic-tasks-in-excel-2010-HA101829993.aspx). [Edit] your question with more detail of how the data is placed in the worksheet will help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also, your question is limited to how to use VLOOKUP. Are you open to other solutions how to retrieve your weekly data? If so, please state that in your question.

Comment: it's not limited! i'm open to any solution

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple way, though not elegant, would be to copy entire sheet to a new sheet. Add a column and put `1` in that column alongside the first row with data. Drag that cell’s bottom right corner down six rows with `Ctrl` depressed (ie until a 7 appears). Then select the 1:7 block and drag its bottom RH corner, down with `Ctrl` depressed, to the last data row. Select entire worksheet (click top left corner, above ‘1’ and to the left of `A’. then Data and Filter. Click the down arrow in the top row of the added column and uncheck the day sequence you wish to retain (say every ‘6’, click on 6). Select all the rows numbered in blue and Delete Row. Re click Filter.